# How to adjust the text automatically only with CSS, when Border Radius of a TextBox is set to 100px?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

The text in TextBox is not rendering properly instead it gets cut when the **border-radius** CSS property is set to 100px. I'm working on some theme changing application and the user has the privileges to adjust the radius.

*The Text in the round TextBox looks something like this*

[image: Overlapping Text In Round Textbox]
 has following css.

```
textarea {
    width: 99%;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    color: #4C4C4C;
    border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    border-radius: 100px;
}
```

> I want TextBox to render text automatically when there is border-radius applied.

Note: I tried it with padding, but for that I need to updated it when there is no radius.
All other solutions are welcome but without JS

Comment: Jut put the `border-radius` and the `padding` together in the same class definition.

Comment: There is no solution without JS

Comment: Hi @frnt, I've added all the code that I have for TextArea. There are some Form Control BootStrap Classes. Do I need to add them too?

Comment: @MrLister As I've mentioned that if I add padding I need to update its value all the time when the radius changes.

Comment: @MukeshKumar OK, I'll bite. How exactly does the radius change?

Comment: The answer is no, you can't auto adjust the text position with the `border-radius`.

Answer (score 2):

Please check working solution here:

```css
textarea {
    width: 99%;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    color: #4C4C4C;
    border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    -mozborder-radius: 100px;
    -ms-border-radius: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 20px 25px;
}
textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<textarea placeholder="This is text that need to adjust">
</textarea>
```

Comment: any explanation ?

Comment: This is not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just give the `textarea` with radius an extra css class:

```css
textarea {
    width: 99%;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    color: #4C4C4C;
    border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.radius{
    border-radius: 100px;
    padding:0 50px;
}
```

```html
<form>
<textarea>Text text</textarea>
<textarea class="radius">Text text</textarea>
</form>
```